# Error creating new symfony's project and can't use bin/console

Tags: symfony, project, new-operator

I just installed Symfony's cli on Debian via wget, when creating a new project with the new Symfony project --full, the following error appears:

> Executing script cache: delete [KO] [KO] Script cache: delete
>   returned with error code 1 !! Could not open input file: ./bin/console
>   !!
>       Script @ auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd unable to execute / usr / local / bin / composer create-project
>       symfony / website-skeleton / home / dwes / project Final: exit status 1

Composer generates the directory structure except bin, I try to ignore the error but obviously when I use any php bin/console command I can't open it:

> root @ dwes2daw: / home / dwes / project Final php bin / console make:
>   controller Could not open input file: bin / console
>
> Thanks for your time

Comment: I had something similar happen to me a few days ago.  I ended up with a vendor directory containing Symfony flex as well as a composer.json file.  I ran "composer install" and everything seemed to come down and install correctly.  Just a guess but maybe give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with https://github.com/symfony/recipes. They have fixed it and now you can create your project.